Host found with same name, different IP address in the domain
I have a Windows Server 2008 domain controller with DNS and DHCP services.
This machine is called server and has a static ip of 192.168.10.201. I used a network scanner and found a machine named SERVER with IP address:
192.168.10.41.
It has the same MAC address and name.
I'm sure two machines are the same. I manually deleted the address record 192.168.10.41 in DNS, but after restarting, it appeared again with the same error and this time it was a different IP address.
When I use the ping server command, it sometimes relays with the address 192.168.10.201 or an address 192.168.10.41. This makes shared folders sometimes accessible and sometimes inaccessible.
I don't understand what's wrong?


What does the network configuration show? Does your server have a second IP address configured?

More basically, a lot of servers have two network adapters are they both plugged in?

@DavidT Yes. Server have two network adapters but I disable one network adapter.
